# @Query Update in Android Room Database doesn't update primary key field

Tags: android, sql, sql-update

I'm writing Android app with Room Database. My database contains GroupVc entity with such code:

```
@Entity
public class GroupVc {

@ColumnInfo(name = "language")
private String language;


@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "name_group")

private String nameGroup;

public GroupVc(String language, String nameGroup) {
    this.language = language;
    this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setLanguage(String language) {
    this.language = language;
}

@NonNull
public String getNameGroup() {
    return nameGroup;
}

@NonNull
public void setNameGroup(String nameGroup) {
    this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
}
}
```

As you can see my entity class contains two columns where nameGroup is my PrimaryKey. In my application I want to let the user to see the full list of groups and change the name of Group DialogFragments by entering new Group's names. To implement such function I've created the next DAO @Query method:

```
@Dao
public interface GroupVcDao {
@Query("UPDATE groupvc SET name_group= :newName WHERE name_group= :currentName")
void updateNameOfGroup(String currentName, String newName);
}
```

In this QUERY I want to change name of GroupVc by getting the existing name of GroupVc from RecyclerView (currentName param) and applying new one from DialogFragment (newName param).
My problem is that this QUERY doesn't bring any effect and doesn't update the name. Although I don't get any errors or exceptions. So I need to know: does such QUERY correct? Is it possible to write Update queries where primary key is changeable value and condition at the same time?

Here is the link to my complete project on GitHub
https://github.com/LAHomieJob/VocaNote

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same issue

Comment: MAN ! you save my life !! THANKS !!

Comment: Way to go!!! Was looking for this all over the place.. and there you go! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but my guess would be that your query is working, but since you're changing the primary key your database is left with an instance of the old object as well as the new one. Try checking to see if you have an object with both the old name_group and the new name_group. Also if you're looking to allow your users to change the group name, it may make sense to move your primary key to a UUID or some other key that doesn't change.